# An error occurred while running the simulation and the simulation was terminated

Tags: matlab, simulink

I keep getting the error below:

Continuous state '1' of 'untitled/Battery/Model/Current filter' at time 0.00010049124961226976 is not finite. Simulink will terminate the simulation. There may be a singularity in the solution. Check the model 'untitled' for errors. Try reducing the fixed step size or tighten the error tolerances for variable-step solvers.

The image of the model is as below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkCBl.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVzr6.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cDOW.png

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

I would need more information, but have you tried changing the solver parameters?
Usually with block from sympowersystems (or similar) I have better numeric performance using a stiff solver, like ode23tb.
To do so, go to your Model Settings (Ctrl + E), go to Solver, Select Variable Step Solver and in the droplist select ode23tb.

Comment: I have tried changing the variable step solver as you have stated but the error still persists.